# Excel Refresh and Save without any prompts

Tags: excel, vba, vb.net, automation

I have the following code to open and refresh an Excel file then save, this works fine apart from a couple of files I have that have a Before_Close event that makes some changes to a sheet.

When I use the VB Net code on these workbooks it prompts and asks if I am sure I want to save changes when closing.

I have similar code to do same but via VBA in an Excel file and I don't get the prompt it just saves and overwrites, is there anything I can do with the VB net code to stop this.

```
  Dim XLApp As Object
  Dim WBook As WorkBook

  XLApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
  XLApp.Visible = False
  XLApp.DisplayAlerts = False 

  WBook = XLApp.workbooks.Open("Y:\Test.xlsb")
  WBook.Refreshall()
  WBook.Save()
  WBook.Close()

  XLApp.Quit()

  WBook = Nothing
  XLApp = Nothing
```

Cheers

Comment: Quick Question: Do you want that event to be fired and then save your file or you want to prevent firing of that event?

Comment: I would like the event to fire as it should which it is doing but not ask me if I am sure, I am trying to automate some excel reports so I can set different emails schedules etc.

Answer (score 0):

I seem to have a fix, but requires modifying the excel files themselves which is not ideal.

As one of my reports needs to modify a sheet when its closed in preparation for next time opened, this workaround seems to stop it from re-asking if sure to save.

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)

   If Not Me.Saved Then   
      Call sbWritePivotWhenClosing
      Me.Save
      Me.Saved = True       
    Else  
     Call sbWritePivotWhenClosing
     Me.Saved = True
    End If
  End Sub
```